# Automatically add category to post for each user on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Sorry for my English. I need your help, if anyone has the time. I would need code to add a category upon new user account and create it in the user's name. thanks a lot for your help

I've searched a bit for information but it's beyond my skills.

add_action('user_register', 'create_taxonomy_name_user'); function create_taxonomy_name_user( $user_id ) { }

Comment: You need this hook - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/ and trigger this function - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/ .

Comment: Thx for help. I have a start of code. I don't see how to now create a new category in the articles in relation to the name of the new user   add_action('user_register', 'create_taxonomy_name_user');
function create_taxonomy_name_user( $user_id ) {
    
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the function in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function create_term_from_username($user_id) {
    // Get the user data
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

    //Change if you want term from any other user data
    $username = $user_info->user_login;

    //Define in which taxonomy we want to add term 
    $taxonomy = 'category';

    // Create a term based on the username
    $term_args = array(
        'slug' => sanitize_title($username), // Sanitize the username to make it suitable for a term slug
    );

    // Insert the term and get its ID
    $term_id = wp_insert_term($username, $taxonomy, $term_args);

    // Check if the term was created successfully
    if (is_wp_error($term_id)) {
        // Handle error if term creation fails
        error_log('Error creating term for user ' . $username . ': ' . $term_id->get_error_message());
    }
}
add_action('user_register', 'create_term_from_username');
```

Comment: It's good
Thanks a lot for your help.
I wish you all the happiness in the world.